# Elastic search update & refresh API

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nestjs

I am integrating elastic search with my Nest application. positing my workflow and question below.

flow:

- front-end updating one entity, so in back-end updates the primary storage MYSQL and cache storage elastic search.
- Immediately front-end hit the get request to get the updated entity, so the back-end fetches the entity from elastic-search and sends a response to the front-end.
- Now the issue is sometimes elastic search giving not updated data due to index not refreshed.

Solutions:

- We can use the `refresh:'wait-for'` config in the update API.
- We can trigger the refresh API to refresh the indices

  - The question is, after the update API, if we trigger the refresh API without waiting for the result. in meantime, if the front-end requested the data what will happen, the elastic search will wait for the refresh indices operation completion or will it serve old data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know Elasticsearch provides [near real time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/near-real-time.html) searches, and if you are making a search call, as soon as document is indexed to Elasticsearch, it will not be available unless `refresh` happened on the index.

Now, As you mentioned, you can solve the issue by using the `wait_for` with your index/update operation, only downside is that its resource intensive and  if you do it frequently on a large index, it can cause severe performance issues in your cluster.

Your second option will not work, as you can still query the Elasticsearch from FE before refresh finishes and you will get obsolete data.

Comment: Small correction: [GET calls are real-time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#realtime) and thus don't need refresh to happen and will return the document from memory as soon as it is indexed